# need a simple way to slidetoggle menu

Tags: menu, toggle, slide

There is a simple slidetoggle effect in menu but i need to make it multiple slidetoggle menu. If i click a menu, all others has to be close. How can i make it clearly and simple?

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
 $('.menu').click(function(e) {
  $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
 });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-content{display:none;position:absolute;}
.active{display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="menu">menu1</a>
<div class="dropdown-content active">content1</div>
  
<a href="#" class="menu">menu2</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">content2</div>
  
<a href="#" class="menu">menu3</a>
<div class="dropdown-content">content3</div>
```